# how to count a repeated char from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

imagine you have this string

```
'49999494949'
'4949999949'
'4949499994'
```

how do you count the most repeated of this  9 in one line after the 4 and print it out as '99999'

i tried

```
a = '49999494949'
b = "123456780"
for char in b:
    a = a.replace(char, "")

return a
```

but it's end up giving me all the 9 in the given string where i want only the most repeated 9 in line after the 4

and thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each string on `"4"`, which will give you a list of strings containing `"9"`. Then you can find the longest:

```py
>>> s = "49999494949"
>>> nines = s.split("4")
>>> nines
['', '9999', '9', '9', '9']
>>> max(nines)
'9999'
```

Or as a single command:

```py
>>> s = "49999494949"
>>> max(s.split("4"))
'9999'
```